# Loader_Generate_Nation_Script is not creating the scripts

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiger, file-path

I'm working on setting up the TIGER geocoder on a Linux machine. I have installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS, now I'm working on the extension, point 2.8.1 of this [guide](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder):

I'm having problems with the points 4 to 8, since after running:

```
psql -c "SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('debbie')" -d geocoder -tA > /gisdata/nation_script_load.sh
```

The output script `nation_script_load.sh` is not been created.

I'm not getting any error at his point, just that the output folder is empty.

I guess the error is at some point during the step 4, but I'm not able to find it. I edited the corresponding paths as mention in the above tutorial: *And then edit the paths in the declare_sect column to those that fit Debbie's pg, unzip,shp2pgsql, psql, etc path locations*

```
update tiger.loader_platform set declare_sect=
UNZIPTOOL=”/usr/bin/unzip”                   
WGETTOOL="/usr/bin/wget"          
export PGBIN=”/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin”   
export PGPORT=5432                
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGUSER=postgres            
export PGPASSWORD= my_password
export PGDATABASE=test1
PSQL=${PGBIN}/psql                
SHP2PGSQL=${PGBIN}/shp2pgsql';
```

> EDIT:

After trying using:

```
psql -d test1 -A -t   -c "SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('sh')"
```

I'm getting this output:

```
TMPDIR="/gisdata/temp/"
UNZIPTOOL=unzip
WGETTOOL="/usr/bin/wget"
export PGBIN=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin
export PGPORT=5432
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGUSER=postgres
export PGPASSWORD=yourpasswordhere
export PGDATABASE=geocoder
PSQL=${PGBIN}/psql
SHP2PGSQL=${PGBIN}/shp2pgsql
cd /gisdata

cd /gisdata
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE/ --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=1 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html 
cd /gisdata/ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE
rm -f ${TMPDIR}/*.*
${PSQL} -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger_staging CASCADE;"
${PSQL} -c "CREATE SCHEMA tiger_staging;"
for z in tl_*state.zip ; do $UNZIPTOOL -o -d $TMPDIR $z; done
for z in */tl_*state.zip ; do $UNZIPTOOL -o -d $TMPDIR $z; done
cd $TMPDIR;

${PSQL} -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.state_all(CONSTRAINT pk_state_all PRIMARY KEY (statefp),CONSTRAINT uidx_state_all_stusps  UNIQUE (stusps), CONSTRAINT uidx_state_all_gid UNIQUE (gid) ) INHERITS(tiger.state); "
${SHP2PGSQL} -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" tl_2015_us_state.dbf tiger_staging.state | ${PSQL}
${PSQL} -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower('state'), lower('state_all')); "
    ${PSQL} -c "CREATE INDEX tiger_data_state_all_the_geom_gist ON tiger_data.state_all USING gist(the_geom);"
    ${PSQL} -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.state_all"
cd /gisdata
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/COUNTY/ --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=1 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html 
cd /gisdata/ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/COUNTY
rm -f ${TMPDIR}/*.*
${PSQL} -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger_staging CASCADE;"
${PSQL} -c "CREATE SCHEMA tiger_staging;"
for z in tl_*county.zip ; do $UNZIPTOOL -o -d $TMPDIR $z; done
for z in */tl_*county.zip ; do $UNZIPTOOL -o -d $TMPDIR $z; done
cd $TMPDIR;

${PSQL} -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.county_all(CONSTRAINT pk_tiger_data_county_all PRIMARY KEY (cntyidfp),CONSTRAINT uidx_tiger_data_county_all_gid UNIQUE (gid)  ) INHERITS(tiger.county); " 
${SHP2PGSQL} -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" tl_2015_us_county.dbf tiger_staging.county | ${PSQL}
${PSQL} -c "ALTER TABLE tiger_staging.county RENAME geoid TO cntyidfp;  SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower('county'), lower('county_all'));"
    ${PSQL} -c "CREATE INDEX tiger_data_county_the_geom_gist ON tiger_data.county_all USING gist(the_geom);"
    ${PSQL} -c "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_tiger_data_county_all_statefp_countyfp ON tiger_data.county_all USING btree(statefp,countyfp);"
    ${PSQL} -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.county_all_lookup ( CONSTRAINT pk_county_all_lookup PRIMARY KEY (st_code, co_code)) INHERITS (tiger.county_lookup);"
    ${PSQL} -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.county_all;"
    ${PSQL} -c "INSERT INTO tiger_data.county_all_lookup(st_code, state, co_code, name) SELECT CAST(s.statefp as integer), s.abbrev, CAST(c.countyfp as integer), c.name FROM tiger_data.county_all As c INNER JOIN state_lookup As s ON s.statefp = c.statefp;"
    ${PSQL} -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.county_all_lookup;"
```

Is that the spected result?

Comment: what happens if you connect to the database and run `SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('debbie')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('debbie');
```

You'll see nothing is outputted. That's because [`Loader_Generate_Nation_Script`](http://postgis.net/docs/Loader_Generate_Nation_Script.html) has a signature of,

```
text loader_generate_nation_script(text os);
```

So it expects it's first argument to be the operating system, currently `windows`, or `sh`. Try

```
psql -d geocoder -A -t \
  -c "SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('sh')" > /gisdata/nation_script_load.sh
```

Instead. And, when in doubt [try to follow the instructions](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder) it can be finicky.

Comment: Now I'm getting a permission error:  "Permission denied"  Even I change the destination folder

Comment: Whatever output directory you're trying for, you do not have write permissions to it. Try running it without the redirection to a file and see if it works.

Comment: I tried with: "psql -d test1 -A -t   -c "SELECT Loader_Generate_Nation_Script('sh')"" I update the question, not sure if I'm getting the correct output.

Comment: Also, why is it in the documentation "debbie" instead of "sh"? does that debbie stand for windows?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez you can either modify the `windows` or `sh` profiles, or create your own. In those docs, in 2.8.4, they add a new profile called `debbie`. I assume you skipped that step, or it should work?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez you either need to edit the columns in the respective row in the table `tiger.loader_platform`: pgadmin will help in this.